# Copy from one table to another table containing an extra column foreign key

Tags: sql

I want to insert the values from `table A` into another table B. The problem is Table B contains another few columns which are foreign keys.

- `Table A` : `ID, Fatherid, MotherID, ParentOccupation`
- `Table B` : `ID, Fatherid, MotherID, ParentOccupation, TrID`

In `Table B` `Trid` is foreign key. But I wish to copy all the other columns from table A to B.

Is it possible to copy the rows from table A to Table B?

Please help.

Comment: well I don't think somebody can help you without sample data, at least

Comment: is not null specified in all fk columns? if not then you can insert into table B with null values for the fk columns

Comment: foreign key to which table?show your table structure and some data

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table_b
select
    col1,
    col2,
    col3, 
    ...
    (select some_key_value
     from some_primary_table
     where <some condition based on table_a's values>),
    (select some_key_value2
     from some_primary_table2
     where <some condition based on table_a's values>),
    ...
from table_a
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just insert corresponding columns,other than foreign key in tableB. IF it is not null
specified in all fk columns of tableB,then insert null value correspondingly

```
insert into tableB(col1,colu2..) 
values (select col1,col2.. from tableA)
```